# liferay plugin development in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, gradle, liferay, liferay-6

I want to develop a plugin in eclipse using ant. 
But I don't use ant without proxy and had to use proxy. And when I use proxy I get this exception:

```
[exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of
    120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: 
    C:\Users\Narges\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-
    bin\88n1whbyjvxg3s40jzz5ur27\gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip
```

What should I do? And is there anyway to build liferay project without ant  ?

Comment: What does this question have in common with gradle?

Comment: @Maryam you can use maven instead of using ant for creating a liferay project.